# directory input sanitation

Tags: linux, perl, scripting

I have a very simple perl script that moves files (don't ask why i cant use cp, its long, sad, and will make you cry). I take 2 inputs from command line, dir1 and dir2. Then i have an internal file list i pull and concatenate the two together.

```
my $file = dir1 . filename
```

That works great as long as the user puts a traling / on their directory. But obviously if they don't it still concatenates it as /my/awesome/folderFILE and the scripts fails.

What is the best practice for sanitizing user supplied directories?

Comment: Why can't you use cp? Maybe this relates to your answer.

Comment: There are plenty of perfectly valid Perl-centric reasons not to use `cp` over Perl's built-in `File::Copy`, of course. But I want to hear the sad story please!

Comment: We have 6.5 million images in a single folder. (not my doing) Doing an ls will end up eating all ram and swap space. A cp -a would probably work, but if it failed I would have no way to resume and I believe would take longer than my "opendir" perl script that can read all 6 million files in about 10 seconds.

Comment: It's obviously too late to help the OP but I've found that I can speed up and reduce the memory usage of my version of `ls` for large directories by passing the `-U` option which turns off sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can, as other answers alluded to, just force-add a trailing slash, it has some minor problems stemming from resulting double-slash - from just looking plain ugly, at least IMHO, if you print the resulting filenames for logging; to a much worse problem of making said logs harder to parse/process automatically if needed.

A more portable and idiomatic approach in Perl is to build the paths using File::Spec:

```
use File::Spec;
my $file = File::Spec::catfile($dir1,$filename);
```

If you feel like using a module for something THAT simple is a bit of a nuke-the-fly approach, use the regex ([so you can now have 2 problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)! :)

```
$dir =~ s!([^/])$!$1/!;
```

This approach has the added benefit of a teaching device to showcase that you don't have to use forward slashes as regex delimiters.

In addition, and probably already obvious to you, but worth re-iterating: **NEVER TRUST THE USER INPUT!!!**

So, always do something like `die "Not a directory: $dir1\n" unless -d $dir1;` when processing command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just always add on a trailing '/' for the directory path.  Your shell should accept '/my/awesome/folder//FILE' and will interpret it as '/my/awesome/folder/FILE'.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $file = $dir1 . '/' . $filename
```

`/a/b//c` works the same as `/a/b/c`

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the requirement to "add a trailing / to the path unless it already has one" from English to Perl quite directly, no regex required:

```
$path .= '/' unless substr($path, -1) eq '/';
```